# obtener informacion del equipo con python

Tags: python-3.x

me preguntaba de que manera pueda obtener a modo de texto información del equipo usando python. Por dar un ejemplo, algún módulo o librería con una función o etc. que me devuelva valores de strings sobre procesador, CPU, etc, cualquier información del equipo que pueda obtener. Esto debido a que estoy en primer año de ing. En sistemas de información, y necesito poder desarrollar un reloj digital que de ser posible muestre estos datos.

Comment: Si usar librerias de terceros no es un problema, entonces empieza por [psutil](https://pypi.org/project/psutil/), puedes obtener información más que de sobra para lo que requieres.

Comment: La pregunta tal como está es muy amplia y basada en opiniones/recomendaciones, pero si decides usar psutil o otra librería en concreto (para SO concretos pueden existir soluciones  vía API del SO directamente) y tienes problemas para obtener la información que quieres, edita especificando la librería y que quieres obtener exactamente para que podamos ayudar. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta libreria te puede ser util:

```
import platform as pl 

datos_sistema_operativo = [
   'architecture',
   'linux_distribution',
   'mac_ver',
   'machine',
   'node',
   'platform',
   'processor',
   'python_build',
   'python_compiler',
   'python_version',
   'release',
   'system',
   'uname',
   'version',
]
for perfil in datos_sistema_operativo:
  if hasattr(pl, perfil):  # aqui preguntamos con el metodo hasattr si para la pataforma "pl" contamos con el atributo actual.
    print('%s:%s' % (perfil, getattr(pl, perfil)()))
```

como puedes ver, entrega datos como la arquitectura, la plataforma, el procesador etc.
espero te sirva. :)

Comment: https://recursospython.com/guias-y-manuales/platform-sistema-y-ordenador/ Te puede servir este sitio web.